# Where to place format functions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dapper, n-tier-architecture

I am building my first n-tier application.

- The first tier is a ASP.net website.
- The second is the business tier.
- The third is the data tier with dapper.

The second and third layer are used in different websites.

When i have a numeric field for the tax option.
*1 = High BTW and 2=Low btw and 3 = No btw*
Is it a good design to make an translate function in the business Artikel class?
If the answer is no, where is the correct place to translate values.
I use this function in the view to show the text instead of the number.

Example:

```
Public Function ArtBtwShow() As String
    Return ArtikelHelper.GetBtwName(ArtBtw)
End Function
```

GetBtwName Helper function:

```
Shared Function GetBtwName(Btw As String)
    Select Case Btw
        Case "0"
            Return "Geen"
        Case "1"
            Return "Laag"
        Case "2"
            Return "Hoog"

        Case Else
            Return ""
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Can you  use an enumeration in the business logic instead of converting between strings?  Or if `BTW` is indicative of a business model then make it a strongly-typed business object?  It sounds like you're passing around some "magic values" that you need to manually convert from one "magic value" to another "magic value".  The answer isn't where to put that conversion, the answer is to not use them in the first place.

Comment: I can change the type of ArtBtw to an Enumarable. But how can i set then yhe display value of a Enumarable item?

Comment: *Should* it be an `Enumerable`?  That's really a matter for how your modeling is structured.  If it's an `Enumerable<T>` then you can display an element by selecting that element from the collection and, well, displaying it.  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like you need to use an Enum rather than a string for your Btw object:

```
Public Enum Btw
    Green = 0
    Laag = 1
    Hoog = 2
End Enum
```

I think the business layer is the place to put this.

You then retrieve the decription like so:

```
Public Funtion GetName(btw As Btw)
    return [Enum].GetName(GetType(Btw), (int)btw)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I try to change the string to an Enum.

Comment: The DisplayFor function in MVC showes the string name